# Facebook Login Review Failed

Tags: ios, facebook, review, publish-actions

We've sent a simulator build of our app to Facebook to get approved our publish actions. But it is rejected as below;

> After I clicked on the Facebook Login button, the app crashed.
>   I attached an error log. Can you check to see if you are providing me
>   with the correct file and that it is working properly?
>
> Your app downloads successfully, but crashes upon opening.
>   Please resolve any technical issues that prevent us from testing your
>   app.

We've already tested our simulator build with ios-sim with different device types and build types (7.1 and 8.1). Logs attached haven't meant much to us;

```
Mar  3 09:56:19 pdo-mbp.dhcp.thefacebook.com Facebook[67913]: 2015-03-03 09:56:19.454 [error][core.app][tid:NSManagedObjectContext 0x796c6400][FBQuickPromotionMultistepInterstitialViewController prepareWithServerContext:] *** Assertion failure: Server context doesn't have any promotion entities.
Mar  3 09:56:21 pdo-mbp assertiond[67878]: assertion failed: 14C109 12B411: assertiond + 11523 [3F572A0B-7E12-378D-AFEE-EA491BAF2C36]: 0x1
Mar  3 09:56:21 pdo-mbp com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.55726B74-1686-4DEC-97C0-3845FF2BE786.launchd_sim[67863] (UIKitApplication:com.facebook.Wilde[0xc820][67913]): Service exited due to signal: Abort trap: 6
Mar  3 09:56:21 pdo-mbp.dhcp.thefacebook.com SpringBoard[67874]: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.facebook.Wilde[0xc820]' crashed.
Mar  3 09:56:21 pdo-mbp.dhcp.thefacebook.com assertiond[67878]: notify_suspend_pid() failed with error 7
Mar  3 09:56:21 pdo-mbp assertiond[67878]: assertion failed: 14C109 12B411: assertiond + 11523 [3F572A0B-7E12-378D-AFEE-EA491BAF2C36]: 0x1
Mar  3 09:56:22 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
```

Does anyone around here had the same issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've sent again the same simulator build to Facebook review. But this time we told them to reset their simulator before launching the app. Now this time it is approved. Looks like It wasn't our fault.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is trying to fetch objects from the Core Data database but it can't find any entries of type "promotion". If you delete the app from your phone and/or simulator and run it again, I would think that you would get the same error as the reviewers at Facebook.

Comment: I had the same issue as OP, i.e. my app got rejected with the same reason and error log. I just tried what you suggested, and the app does not crash after reinstalling the app.

Comment: @kkarayannis, we've already tried "Reset contents & settings" option in the simulator but it is still same, no crash. We couldn't succeed to reproduce it somehow. Tried the simulator build with different macs etc.